# How to change in Sqlite the order of the results?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm working on a site where I showing results on a chart grouped by date but I like to show only the last three results.

In `ASC` order the the first point of the chart starts on the left side but if I have more than three results the first three appears and thats ot what I want.

If I order my result in `DESC` by the `date` it changing the order and it is OK but the last three results (that I need) takes the firs places on the left side (like on the image).
[image]

I like to show the last three results from left to right. How could I do that?

This is what I have now:

```
SELECT * FROM table
GROUP BY strftime("%%Y-%%m", date) 
ORDER BY max(strftime("%%Y-%%m", date)) DESC 
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: remove the `DESC`.

Comment: If I do it it shows the first three and not the last three despite of `max()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you wrap in another query?

like:

```
select *
from(
    SELECT thedate, thedata FROM table
    GROUP BY strftime("%%Y-%%m", date) 
    ORDER BY max(strftime("%%Y-%%m", date)) DESC 
    LIMIT 3
) details

order by details.thedate
```